# Can sendmail DSNs be disabled?

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, dsn

I would like to disable/prevent SendMail from sending a notification if delivery of an email has been delayed.  By default, sendmail sends this out after 4 hours.

What's the best way to do this? Can I set confTO_QUEUEWARN to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to disable/prevent SendMail from sending a notification if delivery of an email has been delayed.

You **must** to know:

1. Disabling DSN is **not recommended** settings
2. STFW can help always
3. If you can't read and understand sendmail.mc, you aren't postmaster

> What's the best way to do this?

RTFM. Namely - confPRIVACY_FLAGS and noreceipts flag

> `noreceipts` causes sendmail to ignore the `NOTIFY=SUCCESS DSN` extension of the `RCPT To:` command and to ignore `Return-Receipt-To:` headers. When `noreceipts` is used, sendmail does not advertise or support DSN... it is not recommended that you use it either...